# Set fill style and flood fill uses

Tags: c++, graphics, codeblocks

what is the use of set fill style and flood fill

Even if I write color is dark gray then it shows green color,then what is the use of flood fill we can simply write only set fill style ?

```
setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, GREEN);
floodfill(55,58,DARKGRAY);
```

But if I didn't give flood fill then nothing will be displayed, what is the link between setfillstyle and flood fill?

Answer (score 0):

`setfillstyle` determines how the area will be filled. Whether it will be patterned, solid or transparent (or no fill).

So, default must be no fill.

From the documentation of `floodfill` at I can see the documentation at http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h/floodfill it looks like that passed color is border color, not fill color.

Comment: It also determines the color whatever i give in setfillstyle only that color is displayed but not the color in floodfill then what is the use of flood fill since setfill fill only decides which pattern should be and what color should be